# How allow a single change of css style when click on a text in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have many green strings:
style.css:

```
.green_text {
  color: green;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;

}
.green_text:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

index.html:

```
<span class="green_text">text 1</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 2</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 3</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 4</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 5</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 6</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 7</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 8</span><br>
```

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".green_text").click(function(){
    $(this).css("color","red");
})
})
```

I want when I clicked text1 the color changes to red but when I clicked text2 only the color of text2 will be red and text 1 will be green. How can I do that with many strings.

Comment: What did you tried ?

Comment: @NathanP. Op posted what he already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just on click of the `.green_txt` change css of other to `green`  and for **current** add **color** **red**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".green_text").click(function() {
   $(".green_text").css("color","green");
    $(this).css("color", "red");
  })
})
```

> Below is the working Snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".green_text").click(function() {
   $(".green_text").css("color","green");
    $(this).css("color", "red");
  })
})
```

```css
.green_text {
  color: green;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.green_text:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="green_text">text 1</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 2</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 3</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 4</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 5</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 6</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 7</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 8</span><br>
```

Answer (score 2):

On click set all the element's color to `green` then change only the clicked element's color to `red`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".green_text").click(function(){
      $(".green_text").css("color","green");
      $(this).css("color","red");
  })
})
```

```css
.green_text {
  color: green;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;

}
.green_text:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="green_text">text 1</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 2</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 3</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 4</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 5</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 6</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 7</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 8</span><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I'd strongly suggest adding/removing a class over setting `css()` in JS code. From there you can use `siblings().removeClass()` to do what you need. Also note that setting `pointer` in the `:hover` state is redundant. Just put it in the `.green_text` class directly. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".green_text").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  })
})
```

```css
.green_text {
  color: green;
  font: bold 20px Arial;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.green_text.active { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="green_text">text 1</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 2</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 3</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 4</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 5</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 6</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 7</span><br>
<span class="green_text">text 8</span><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want when I clicked text1 the color changes to red but when I clicked text2 only the color of text2 will be red and text 1 will be green.

You can just turn remaining to green first.

```
$(".green_text").click(function(){
    $(".green_text").css("color","green");
    $(this).css("color","red");
})
```

Comment: `$(".green_text").css("color","green");`